# How to deal with a YouTube video that have been watched before

Tags: javascript, video, browser, youtube, youtube-dl

I have a question after viewing the way that yt-dl (and its branches) work, it is as easy as requesting a video like any regular user and doing the reconstruction and collecting the whole thing as one file. I have to assert that it is not a superuser question!

Is there a way (even a not mature one) to deal programmatically (I think JS is the only one that I ask for here) with the segments of a video from youtube for example so that we do not need to download the whole video from the beginning if we have watched a video and decided that we want to keep it offline? Assuming that the whole video is still in the RAM (storage tab in the developer's tools)

OS: Windows   Browser: Chrome   PL: JS

**Answers to this question are going to be the seed of a browser extension project**

Comment: please, [edit] your question and add the code you're using, see how to create a [mcve]. **Stack Overflow is not specifically a code-writing service** because you can't ask for any arbitrary code and expect to get an answer. Show us what have you tried.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance in my first question, I already know what you have said. I have searched and found nothing so I need a small hint to start. Though, I am tinkering now and may find something to add here soon. An upvote may be helpful here if you think that this may help me.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your video, may be. I have seen people segmenting the videos like chapters/parts. If you can do that, you should be able to take part of the video.

I also find this video that explains it:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5i5Oo4oj9AhXBNuwKHWtMAMcQtwJ6BAgKEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuuZZFVMoE_U&usg=AOvVaw0LMgqUzgu9nUzvxe63jQ-m

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding here. I am asking for a different thing. please take your time reading the question again if you would like to help.